# SQL construct for particular output. Can one query give me this

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Afternoon.  I am using SQLServer 2008r2, I have this SQL:

```
SELECT dateName(mm,wfi.created) AS theMonth
, datePart(yyyy,wfi.created) AS theYear
, count(wf.WebFormsIndexID) AS numOfForms
FROM WebFormsInstances as wfi
LEFT OUTER JOIN WebFormsIndex as wf on wfi.webFormsIndexID = wf.WebFormsIndexID
where  year(wfi.created) = year(getDate())
group by datePart(yyyy,wfi.created), datePart(mm,wfi.created), dateName(mm,wfi.created)
order by theYear,datePart(mm,wfi.created)
```

which gives me total number of all forms submitted by the month:

```
January     2015    799
February    2015    1282
March       2015    1450
...
```

There are around 50 different forms.  The form name is wf.formName How can I restructure this so I can get total numbers for each individual form for each month.  Something like:

```
myFormName1    January    2015    220
myFormName2    January    2015    179
```

I can figure out how to do this in two queries but would ideally like to do it in one? The objective is a report, form names down the page, months across the page with total number of forms in play for each month.

Comment: Which column in which table holds the form name?  You need to select it, and list it in the GROUP BY clause (as the first column) and in the ORDER BY clause.  Not very hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    wf.formName 
    dateName(mm,wfi.created) AS theMonth, 
    datePart(yyyy,wfi.created) AS theYear, 
    count(wf.WebFormsIndexID) AS numOfForms
FROM WebFormsInstances as wfi
LEFT OUTER JOIN WebFormsIndex as wf on wfi.webFormsIndexID = wf.WebFormsIndexID
where  year(wfi.created) = year(getDate())
group by wf.formName, datePart(yyyy,wfi.created), datePart(mm,wfi.created)
order by wf.formName, datePart(yyyy,wfi.created), datePart(mm,wfi.created)
```